# Display arabic text from txt file to cmd prompt

Tags: windows, command, prompt

I am trying to print **Arabic** on `cmd` prompt from a file named `test.txt`
The contents of test.txt is as below:

```
ASCII              abcde xyz
German             äöü ÄÖÜ ß
Polish             ąęźżńł
Russian            абвгдеж эюя
CJK                你好
Arabic             جيدة هذا هو اختبار
```

`Test.txt` is saved as encoding: `UTF-8` and font: `arial` Unicode ms, script: Arabic
The `cmd` properties has been changed to font `Lucida console` and `chcp` (code page) to `1256`

But still when type `test.txt` throws garbage value in place of **Arabic** text. Is there any work around for displaying this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem like there's a workaround:

> Arabic and Hebrew (and for that matter Thai, Hindi, and other complex scripts) are not supported on Windows 2000 and Windows XP console.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/821083

Comment: Is there a way to print using dos print command in vb script?

Comment: That would be another question, I don't know about VB script but I would expect it to have more sophisticated mechanisms for printing than that...

Comment: Ok. Then i shall post a new question on the same.